# cvBoundingRect not working

Tags: c++, opencv

I am passing output of **cvFindContours** i.e contours to **cvBoundingRect**. But it gives this error:

OpenCV Error: Bad argument (Unsupported sequence type) in cvBoundingRect, file /home/z/src/OpenCV-2.4.2/modules/imgproc/src/shapedescr.cpp, line 950
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
  what():  /home/z/src/OpenCV-2.4.2/modules/imgproc/src/**shapedescr.cpp**:950: error: (-5) Unsupported sequence type in function cvBoundingRect

Here is the code:

```
CvRect rect;
cvFindContours( imgB, g_storage, &contours,sizeof(CvContour),CV_RETR_LIST, CV_CHAIN_CODE,cvPoint(0,0));
if(contours)
{cvDrawContours(img_B,contours, CV_RGB(250,0,0), CV_RGB(0,0,250),1,2,8);
rect=cvBoundingRect(contours);
}
```

Kindly tell me what could be the reason of this error. What is the solution? Thanks

Comment: Ok I found my answer. Here is the correct method:

http://singhgaganpreet.com/tag/cvboundingrect-example/

Answer (score 0):

cvBoundingRect() takes 1 contour, you're feeding all of them into it

Comment: Can you please tell me how do I pass one contour?

Comment: sorry, no idea about the old 1.0 api

Answer (score 0):

Going on from where berak left,
CvSeq** first_contour is what you provide your function.

> The pointer first_contour is filled by the function. It will contain a
>   pointer to the first outermost contour or NULL if no contours are
>   detected (if the image is completely black). Other contours may be
>   reached from first_contour using the h_next and v_next links.

So you would need something like that:

```
CvSeq* contour = *contours;
while (contour != NULL)
{
    //insert boundingbox and other code
    contour = contour->h_next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I found my answer. Here is the correct method:

http://singhgaganpreet.com/tag/cvboundingrect-example/